# How to bind root (/) to itself with fuse on linux?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, mount, fuse

I'm writing a fuse file system that mount one directory to itself. I want to log some calls (`flush` for example). I've started to adapt [fuse tutorial sample code](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/fuse-tutorial.tgz). If I try to bind any directory it works great:

```
./bbfs -o nonempty ./test ./test
```

but if I try to bind particular root directory ("/"):

```
sudo ./bbfs -o nonempty / /
```

no one line is in logfile.

Is it possible?

[My mangled version of sample program](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/36180992/my_fuse.tgz). I've changed only `bbfs.c` file.

Comment: Are you really able to mount a dir to itself? How come? When i try to enter such a directory, the shell freezes. (I tried only the original version of the bbfs so far)

Comment: ...tried your version too and the effect is the same. did you use some specific command line options? 
(sorry for double-post but comments can only be added within 5 mins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mount a FUSE filesystem (or any other type of filesystem, for that matter) at `/`, because your root filesystem is already there.

Doing so would be disastrous anyway, as mounting a filesystem at a path makes any files which previously existed under that path inaccessible. You can't use FUSE as a filter like this -- you will need to find another solution to whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't want to mount "/" over "/". I just want to "bind" it with itself. All calls to rootfs will be delivered to rootfs. No one file will be missed or corrupted. Why I can bind any directory with itself, but `/`? Can you tell me exact reason?

    `because your root filesystem is already there`

all my previous bound directories was already there.

Comment: You can mount filesystems over most other directories because those directories aren't already mount points. `/` is always a mount point, so you can't mount anything else over it.

Comment: This is wrong, you can remount /, how do you think initramfs works? see pivot_root(2) system call.